# Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create FormGroup after getting result from my http service

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .mergeMap((params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        return this.dataStorageDervice.getRezerwacja(this.id);
      }).subscribe(rezerwacja => {
      this.rezerwacja = rezerwacja;
      this.initForm();
    });
  }
  private initForm() {
    let rezerwacjaName = '';
    rezerwacjaName = this.rezerwacja[0][2];
    this.rezerwacjaForm = new FormGroup({
      'nazwisko': new FormControl('pawel', Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

but my html renders faster and it's not recieving FormGroup object, which is created after reaching out http service.
It throws an error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. 
How can i fix that?

Comment: can you show your HTML code ?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="rezerwacjaForm"></form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the FormGroup instance in the constructor and then update or replace it when the data is available.

This should do

```
constructor() {
  this.initForm();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .mergeMap((params: Params) => {
        this.id = +params['id'];
        return this.dataStorageDervice.getRezerwacja(this.id);
      }).subscribe(rezerwacja => {
        this.rezerwacja = rezerwacja;
        this.initForm();
      });
  }

  private initForm() {
    let rezerwacjaName = '';
    if(this.rezerwacja) {
      rezerwacjaName = this.rezerwacja[0][2];
    }
    this.rezerwacjaForm = new FormGroup({
      'nazwisko': new FormControl('pawel', Validators.required)
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you, like this? constructor(private rezerwacjaForm: FormGroup){}
how can i update it?

Comment: thank you, could you also show me how can i update it?

Comment: `FormGroup` has all kinds of methods to do that `addControl`, `removeControl`, `setControl`, ... https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl

Comment: when i try to create new FormGroup() -> supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Comment: Please try `new FormGroup({})`. It's a while I did it myself.

Comment: did that, did also: this.rezerwacjaForm.addControl('nazwisko', new FormControl('pawel', Validators.required));

i've added formControlName="nazwisko" to my input, but I'm getting Cannot find control with name: 'nazwisko'. Somehow it still doesnt see it.

Comment: I see, that's from the view binding. I updated my answer.